# How do I use <input type="date"> and then Date.prototype.getFullYear() in VueJS?

Tags: vuejs2

I simply want to ask the user to input a date and then take actions based on the day/month/year. I don't want to install more dependencies either.

I have:

```
<input type="date" v-model="dateOfBirth" />
```

and:

```
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      dateOfBirth: null,
    };
  },
  ...
```

When I make a selection I get:

```
typeof vm.dateOfBirth === object
```

and the result looks like:

```
2018-05-11
```

But how can I now get the day/month/year, where should the `.getFullYear()` go? It is not working how I expected, I have tried everything online I could find, please help!

Comment: The value of an input of type date is a string. You would have to do something [like this](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/vrOJaQ?editors=1010).

Comment: brilliant, thanks!! do I really need `if (!this.dateOfBirth) {return null;}` every time? I have made year, month and day computed properties and they all start with this, does not seem DRY. I note that I can use vm.year in methods so can do all my calculations. I only started Vue yesterday and love it already, re-writing an app in it to learn and it is going to save a lot of time :)

Comment: The check is just to avoid calling the function on a null value. You could initialize the date and avoid it. I updated the example above.

Comment: thanks for that info!! I found if I keep `dateOfBirth: null` then the result is `Year: 1970 Month: 0 Day: 1` so it does not seem to be able to be null? Does this not make the `if (!this.dateOfBirth) {return null;}` redundant in either case? Do you want to paste this as an answer so I can vote it correct?

Comment: You're right, it may not be strictly necessary; there are some edge cases you will want to handle but I added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of a date input is a string, so in order to call `getFullYear` you need to convert it into a date.

In Vue, you might do that with a computed property. Here is an example.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    dateOfBirth: new Date()
  },
  computed:{
    year(){
      return new Date(this.dateOfBirth).getFullYear()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="date" v-model="dateOfBirth">
  <hr>
  Year: {{year}}
</div>
```

This code doesn't handle all the edge cases, but should give you the idea.